# Python started from WSL can't see environment variables set in calling shell

Tags: python, bash, environment-variables, wsl-2

When I run this code in bash:

```sh
VALUE=BAR python -c 'import os; print(os.environ["VALUE"])'
```

I would expect to see the string `"BAR"` to be printed. I got `KeyError` error instead, indicating that the script didn't receive the environment variable.

I also tried

```
export VALUE=BAR; python -c 'import os; print(os.environ["VALUE"])'
```

and

```
export VALUE=BAR
python -c 'import os; print(os.environ["VALUE"])'
```

but I got the same result.

@Philippe Running `type python; python -V; VALUE=BAR python -c 'import os; print(os.environ["VALUE"])'` results in:

```
python is /usr/local/bin/python
Python 3.9.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Danon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\os.py", line 679, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'VALUE'
```

PS: Perhaps I should've included that, I use WSL and I added symlink `/usr/local/bin/python` to point to `C:\Program Files\Python\python.exe`.

Comment: That all looks fine. When I run any if your examples, I see the output `BAR`. Can you tell us more about your enironment?

Comment: All of these should work. The only explanation I can imagine is that your `python` is an alias or wrapper which explicitly removes the variable you just set before running the real Python.

Comment: It would help if you can run `type python; python -V; VALUE=BAR python -c 'import os; print(os.environ["VALUE"])'` and paste results here.

Comment: @tripleee Yes, `python` is a symlink.

Comment: What are the contents of PYTHONSTARTUP?

Comment: @WilliamPursell Empty or the var doesn't exist, I think. `echo $PYTHONSTARTUP` showed nothing.

Comment: A symlink to what, then? If you have `/usr/local/bin/python` which in turn runs `unset VALUE; exec /usr/bin/pyhon "$@"` that would explain it; but why would you have anything like that?

Comment: @tripleee See my edited question. I don't have `unset VALUE` anywhere.

Comment: Ah, so you single-handedly broke it yourself!

Answer (score 1):

> Perhaps I should've included that, I use WSL and I added symlink /usr/local/bin/python to point to C:\Program Files\Python\python.exe.

Don't do that. Env vars aren't shared by default between WSL processes and Windows processes. See https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/share-environment-vars-between-wsl-and-windows/ for one way to make this work but I don't recommend it. It's better to use the native WSL python program.

Answer (score -1):

This has been frustrating me too, and then I found that the word `export` was missing.

```
$ export VALUE=BAR
$ python3 -c 'import os; print(os.environ["VALUE"])'
BAR
```

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 via WSL2.

--- EDIT ----------------

Whoops. My bad.  I was having this issue and when I found this post I missed the `EXPORT` in the OP's question as well.  What a wiff.

I will leave this up as an example to the future to re-read before posting.  And I shall hang my head in shame...

Comment: The OP's code _does_ contain the `export` keyword in the 2nd and 3rd cases (whereas for a temporary assignment with `VALUE=BAR python ...` all on one line the `export` is implicit and doesn't need to be stated at all), so this is distinct from their problem and thus not responsive to the question at hand.

Comment: Note that to have the same problem, you need to not just be using WSL2, but to have your Python executable _be a Windows-native Python rather than a WSL-native Python_.